# Apache FOP umlaut spacing issue

Tags: diacritics, postscript, apache-fop

I am using Apache FOP version 0.95. I am facing a spacing issue in the ps file :
(Empf\344nger)
[5.464 8.464 5.592 3.376 14.216 5.696 5.592 5.312
3.976]
The word 'Empfänger' is being printed as 'Empfä nger'. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: This must be due to wrong font metrics. What kind of font is this? (OpenType, TrueType, Type 1?)

Comment: The other special characters present are printed correctly. The issue is seen with respect to just this character.The width of just this character is incorrectly generated.The font type used is Type1

Answer (score 0):

can you elaborate a bit more on your exact problem? I have just seen the very same behaviour and was able to solve it like this.

I was generating my own XML files and using the Dom4J XMLWriter with "OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint()" this creates code like this:

```
      <inline font-family="Verdana">L</inline>
      <inline font-family="Verdana">üftungstechnische Ma</inline>
      <inline font-family="Verdana">ßnahme zum Feuchteschutz erforderlich.</inline>
```

Once I switch the output mode to "OutputFormat.createCompactFormat()" everything works fine. The generated output looks like this:

```
      <inline font-family="Verdana">L</inline><inline font-family="Verdana">üftungstechnische Ma</inline><inline font-family="Verdana">ßnahme zum Feuchteschutz erforderlich.</inline>
```

Which is then printed correctly. Now let's hope that it is the same problem in your case.